# cd to directory of a symbolically linked file

Tags: shell, zsh, symlink, cd-command

Before I write a script, anyone know an easy way to do the following:

```
$ pwd
/foo/bar
$ ls -l
lrwxr-xr-x  1 username  admin  48 Apr 17  2012 foo.sh -> /bar/foo.sh
$ cd /bar
$ ls
foo.sh
```

*i.e.,* in the directory `/foo/bar`, I'd like to do something like `cdl` (cd link), which would take me to the directory of the linked file (or alternatively to the linked directory, if that happened to be the case—if it was I could type `cd -P /bar`).

Comment: May I ask what your motivation is for doing this?  Also, do you want to resolve symlinks recursively?  (If /bar is itself a symlink, would you want to follow it?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In zsh, there's a [modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) for that, or rather two: `A` to resolve symbolic links (with [realpath](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath)) and `h` to extract the “head” (i.e. the [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dirname)).

```
cd $file(:A:h)
```

This only works if the symbolic isn't broken. If there is a chain of symbolic links, it is followed until the ultimate target. If the directory was reached through a symbolic link, you'll be in its target (as with `cd -P`).

---

Without zsh, if you have the `readlink` utility, and you want to change to the directory containing the target of the symbolic link:

```
cd -- "$(dirname -- "$(readlink -- "$file")")"
```

The target of the link could be itself a symlink. If you want to change to the directory containing the ultimate target of the link, you can call `readlink` in a loop:

```
while [ -L "$file" ]; do
  target=$(readlink -- "$file")
  while case $target in */) target=${target%/};; *) false;; esac; done
  case $target in
    */*) cd -- "${target%/*}"; target=${target#**/};;
  esac
done
```

On Linux, assuming the symlink isn't broken, you can use `readlink -f` to canonicalize the path:

```
t=$(readlink -f -- "$file")
cd "${t%/*}"
```

Comment: Excellent answer:  `cd $file(:A:h)` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `readlink` to resolve the symbolic link and then `dirname` to get its directory.

```
cdl () {
    cd "$(dirname "$(readlink "$1")")"; 
}
```

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/foo/bar
bash-3.2$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  11 Jun 15 19:10 foo.sh -> /bar/foo.sh
bash-3.2$ cdl foo.sh 
bash-3.2$ pwd 
/bar
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: N.B. this is a perfect example of why to use `$()` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 0):

one line:

```
cd $(dirname $([ -L $0 ] && readlink -f $0 || echo $0))
```

Comment: This is your second one-line answer (it even appears to be exactly the same answer). Again, one-line answers are _not_ the most helpful. Please expand your answers to include more helpful information and explanation (including supporting links and documentation).